# User Controls not referencing on Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm referencing some user controls at the top of my page

however when I try to use the control its saying that the element is not a know element for page_header. I'm tearing my hair out with this can anyone help please?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"          CodeFile="automation_provisioning.aspx.vb" Inherits="customers_automation_provisioning" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="Chessplc.Common.App.UI.Controls" Assembly="Chessplc.Common.App" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="Chessplc.Common.App.UI.Validators" Assembly="Chessplc.Common.App" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/paging_listview.ascx" TagName="paging_listview" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/meta.ascx" TagName="meta" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/page_header.ascx" TagName="page_header" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/page_footer.ascx" TagName="page_footer" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/menu_customers.ascx" TagName="menu_customers" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="../App_UserControls/menu_contract.ascx" TagName="menu_contract" TagPrefix="uc" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <uc:page_header ID="ucHeader" runat="server" />

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div id="main_content">

        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Try to drag&drop the usercontrol onto the designer of this aspx

Comment: thank but this does not work

Comment: What does that mean? Have you removed your own registration and let ASP.NET do it? If you remove it and then drag&drop the UserControl it will be registered automatically.

Comment: Is this true for all controls? Or you have an issue with specific control?

Comment: all of the user controls that I add to the page